# Boost Shared_Ptr assignment

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

Why can I not do this?

```
boost::shared_ptr<QueuList> next;

void QueuList::SetNextPtr(QueuList* Next)
{
    boost::mutex mtx;

    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mtx);
    {// scope of lock
        //if (next == NULL)  // is this needed on a shared_ptr??
        next = Next;  // Why can I not assign a raw ptr to a shared_ptr????
    }
```

}

How should I do it instead??

EDIT:  Calling this method when the next variable is assigned properly, it still causes an error when the QueuList object is destroyed for some reason.  I get a debug assertion.  The destructor of the object does nothing in particular.  It only crashes when I call this function:

```
    QueuList li;
    QueuList lis;

    li.SetNextPtr(&lis);
```

When main goes out of scope, I get a debug assertion... Any ideas??

Comment: Edited my answer for your edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting a pointer inside a `shared_ptr` transfers ownership of the pointer to the shared_ptr, so the `shared_ptr` is responsible for deleting it. This is conceptually an important operation, so the designers of `shared_ptr` didn't want it to just happen as part of a normal-looking assignment. For example, they wanted to prevent code like:

```
some_shared_ptr = some_other_smart_pointer.get();
```

which looks fairly innocuous, but would mean that both smart pointers thought they had responsibility for cleaning up the pointer, and would likely double-delete the pointer or something similar.

This is what's happening with your debug assertion. Calling `SetNextPtr(&lis)` passes ownership of `&lis` to the `shared_ptr`, and "ownership" means that the `shared_ptr` will call `delete` on its pointee when the last copy of the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope. So you're effectively deleting a local (stack) variable - `lis` - which corrupts the stack and causes the crash.

Comment: so if lis is a pointer itself, passing it to this function will cause it to be owned by the shared_ptr or will I still need to delete my lis pointer?

Comment: You won't need to delete the `lis` pointer - you only need to `delete` pointers obtained from `new`, and in fact you must *only* call `delete` on pointers that were returned by `new`. It is incorrect to pass the `lis` pointer to this function at all, as the function currently is written, because `&lis` is not a pointer obtained from `new`, and the function will implicitly `delete` its argument.

Comment: I was talking about a pointer as this: QueuList* lis = new QueuList();

Comment: OK, yes, so if you pass the result of `new QueuList()` to that function, then you don't (and mustn't) delete it anywhere else.

Answer (score 7):

This is done to prevent accidentally assigning pointers to a `shared_ptr` whose lifetime is managed independently. You have to explicitly create a `shared_ptr` that then takes ownership of the object.

```
next = boost::shared_ptr<QueueList>( Next );
```

**Edit about your edit** The problem is that in your case the `shared_ptr` takes ownership of an object on the stack. Then two things can happen:

1. The stack-frame of the object gets cleared before the `shared_ptr` reaches a reference count of 0. In that case, the `shared_ptr` will try to delete a non-existing object somewhere later, leading to undefined behavior.
2. The `shared_ptr` reaches a reference count of 0 before the stack-frame is cleared. In that case, it will try to delete an object on the stack. I do not know exactly what happens in that case, but I would assume that it is undefined behavior too.

Comment: Or just use the reset Member function - `next.reset(Next);`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Reset() function rather than the wordier `next = boost::shared_ptr<QueueList>(Next);`

```
next.Reset(Next);
```